# Xcode 6.1 button with segue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to do view change with segue which activated by login button. But I cannot find performSeguewithIdentifier function in Xcode 6.1. What is the proper way to do that ?

Here is my scenario

User enters mail and password then clicks login button (1)
Application checks user information if it is correct, then next view will be activated (2)

I already did application server connection and information checking so I need a way of opening new view after checking information.

Comment: `performSegueWithIdentifier` is a method of `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Example:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("push", sender: self)

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
if segue.identifier == "push" {

}
```

May be this can help you.

Comment: Yes this is the answer . I think code completion does not work for performseguewithidentifier function. It somehow builds.

Answer (score 0):

You first create IBAction for the button and connect the action to Login button.

after that,

1. Remove the current segue from UIButton
2. ctrl+drag from the source UIViewController to     destination
   UIViewController. (not from login button)
3. select "push".
4. Give an identifier to the segue.

And add the below line after validating the fields,

[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"segue_id" sender:self];