# Go to new view on change of search bar swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to go to a new table view on beginning editing of a search bar in the current view as shown in the picture below.

[image]

So far I have created a segue as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094923/swift-navigate-to-new-viewcontroller-using-button) answer, and used the following code in my current controller with the search bar.

Declarations:

```
lazy   var searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 40, 140, 40))
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
searchBar.delegate = self;
```

and also the following function (`showSearchResults` is the id of the segue):

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar){

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showSearchResults", sender: self)
    }
```

What I want to happen is the new controller to appear when i click onthe search box, but I get this error:

```
2016-07-28 15:42:25.750 ABCApp[7745:3279712] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<ABCApp.HomePageViewController: 0x7b08e910>) has no segue with identifier 'showSearchResults''
*** First throw call stack:

-----

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any idea?

Comment: check your storyboard segue name is `showSearchResults`

Comment: that solved it, thanks!

Comment: great! happy swift coding @toing_toing