# Swift: Using credentials with Firebase and a additional textfield for username

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, authentication

I have a few things I'm trying to accomplish. First, my email and password don't matter if they're filled or not to login. I would like the app to check if email and password is filled and correct before logging in. Secondly, I would like to put in a username when they register so it would show up on the profile page and tell other users who they're without revealing an email address. I'm using Firebase and I thought this would do the trick, but it doesn't. I looked over this [Stack overFlow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094923/swift-navigate-to-new-viewcontroller-using-button) and have everything correct I think, but its still letting you login without credentials.

```
@IBAction func loginRegisterBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "profileVC", sender: self)
    if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error ) in
            if error == nil {
                print("DAW: User Created")
            } else {
               FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error ) in
            if error != nil {
                    print ("DAW: User failed to authenticate with Firebase")
            } else {
                    print ("DAW: Successfully")
                if let user = user {
                    self.completeSignIn(id: user.uid)
                        }
                    }
               })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are performing the segue before it tries to log the user in. You want to move the perform segue to after self.completeSignIn(id: user.uid)

Comment: implicit use of self, use self. to make capture semantic explicit ... i used .self before, but never self.

Comment: I tried nil too, but it has the same error as above

Comment: Did you add: self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "profileVC", sender: self)

Comment: Thanks, but it still lets me login without putting in any creds :-/

Comment: check that emailTextField.text != "" before continuing with the code. Same for the other fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@IBAction func loginRegisterBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text {
        if email != "" && password != ""{
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error ) in
            if error == nil {
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "profileVC", sender: self)
            } else {
                FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error ) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print ("DAW: User failed to authenticate with Firebase")
                    } else {
                        print ("DAW: Successfully")
                        if let user = user {
                            self.completeSignIn(id: user.uid)
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
       }
    }
}
```